# Hook up Grails to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, grails

I am trying to hook up my Grails app to Postgresql. My versions:

Grails Version: 3.2.4
| Groovy Version: 2.4.7
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_60

Postgres installed through Homebrew version 9.6.1
Pouring postgresql-9.6.1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz

added newest postgres jdbc driver in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1206-jdbc4'
}
```

In application.yml under development datasource I've added

```
driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
dbCreate: none
username: myUsername
url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/business
```

I have a domain class named Firm with properties that match the firm table in business database.

```
package bus.proto

class Firm {

    int id
    String firm_name

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Postgres query

```
business=# select * from firm;
 id |  firm_name   
----+--------------
  1 | example_firm
(1 row)

business=#
```

I am now confused as to how to figure out my configuration.  I had rebooted my Mac and not had any instances of Postgresql running.  I the ran

```
brew services start postgres
```

and then ran a

```
sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP
```

to get

```
postgres   807  username    5u  IPv6 0x3ba11f77231b4ebb      0t0    TCP [::1]:5432 (LISTEN)
postgres   807  username    6u  IPv4 0x3ba11f772808980b      0t0    TCP 127.0.0.1:5432 (LISTEN)
```

When I hit the firm/index page I get the exception

```
ERROR: column this_.version does not exist Position: 30
```

thrown by the line

```
def firms = Firm.list()
```

which is located in the index() method in the FirmController.

I'm not sure how to pinpoint the problem after searching for the error message.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Grails domain classes expect a version column in the underlying table unless `version: false` is specified in the mapping block in the domain class.

Comment: @dmahapatro hmmm I added this and still wants a version      `static constraints = { version: false
    }`

Comment: Should add that in static mapping instead of static constraints.

Comment: Ahhh I see, awesome!